# How do I make a Diary in C language?

Tags: c, linux, debian, cs50

First timer here; I'm trying to make a diary program in c following the cs50 reference

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)

{

//Program ask user for their name
string name = GetString("What is your name?\n");
printf("Hello there %s, name\n");

//Program ask user for their age
int age = GetInt("What is your age?\n");
printf("You are %i, old\n");

}
```

When I run the code with clang, it returns this error message

```
Diarytest.c:10:25: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 0,
      have 1
string name = GetString("What is your name?\n");
              ~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/cs50.h:106:1: note: 'GetString' declared here
string GetString(void);
^
Diarytest.c:11:22: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments
      [-Wformat]
printf("Hello there %s, name\n");
                    ~^
Diarytest.c:14:18: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 0,
      have 1
int age = GetInt("What is your age?\n");
          ~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/cs50.h:87:1: note: 'GetInt' declared here
int GetInt(void);
^
Diarytest.c:15:18: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments
      [-Wformat]
printf("You are %i, old\n");
                ~^
2 warnings and 2 errors generated.
```

Is there something that I'm missing here? I installed the cs50 library in my OS and I even tried linking it and it returned the same error message. Thanks for any help! Cheers.

Update: The Code was updated with some help from a User below (Thank you David Cullen) and now the code looks like this.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)

{

//Program ask user for their name
string name = GetString();
printf("Hello there, %s\n", name);

//Program ask user for their age
int age = GetInt();
printf("You are, %i\n", age);

}
```

However, when I run the program with clang I get a new error message.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/Diarytest-862733.o: in function `main':
Diarytest.c:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `GetString'
/usr/bin/ld: Diarytest.c:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `GetInt'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm stumped

Comment: Did you intend to use `get_int` ? See https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/28698/i-have-a-getint-function-issue-pset1

Comment: Also see https://manual.cs50.io/3/get_string

Comment: Also see https://manual.cs50.io/3/get_int

Comment: This might be relevant: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/1483/undefined-reference-to-getstring

Comment: In 2016, those running the CS50 course changed the function interfaces from names like `GetString()` to `get_string()`.  You shouldn't still be trying to use the names with capital letters. It's surprising that you found references to the old names.

Comment: You don't "run the code" with clang, you compile it with clang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
Diarytest.c:10:25: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 0,
      have 1
string name = GetString("What is your name?\n");
              ~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/cs50.h:106:1: note: 'GetString' declared here
string GetString(void);
^
```

This error means you cannot pass `"What is your name?\n"` to `GetString`.

```c
Diarytest.c:11:22: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments
      [-Wformat]
printf("Hello there %s, name\n");
                    ~^
```

This error means you have to supply another parameter to `printf` here (maybe `name`).

```c
Diarytest.c:14:18: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 0,
      have 1
int age = GetInt("What is your age?\n");
          ~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/cs50.h:87:1: note: 'GetInt' declared here
int GetInt(void);
^
```

Similar to the above problem, you cannot pass `"What is your age?\n"` to `GetInt`.

```c
Diarytest.c:15:18: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments
      [-Wformat]
printf("You are %i, old\n");
                ~^
2 warnings and 2 errors generated.
```

Once again, you have to supply another parameter to `printf` here (maybe `age`).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your assistance. Sorry for bothering, but what are my possible solution for getting this to work?